Powershell module SimplySQL can not connect to MySQL server with help of PSCredential: "Cannot convert to System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"
I am trying to use SimplySQL example from their wiki, to connect to MySQL Server which is up and running (MySQL Workbench works fine)
# | Load and Install SimplySQl Module from PSGallery
Install-Module SimplySql -Scope CurrentUser

Import-Module -Name SimplySQL

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "secpwd" -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("sqlwriter", $password)
  
  Open-MySqlConnection -server '192.168.0.70' -connectionname 'localhost' -database 'mydb' -Credential Cred

  $testconnection = Test-SqlConnection -ConnectionName 'localhost'
  $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO table1 (value1, value2) VALUES (@label1, @label2)"
  Close-SqlConnection -connectionname 'localhost'


I have an error:
Open-MySqlConnection: Failed to bind parameter 'Credential'. Cannot convert value "Cred" of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential".

Obviously, there is someting wrong with this credential object, but what? It completely mimicks microsoft tutorial. I just do not understand why it can not transform to secure string while it is stated in script. wtf...

Cred --> $Cred? In your Open-MySqlConnection line.

It was first what I try to change, yet it generates an error message wich indicates that mysql cannot conect to server. I doublechecked and in their wiki is is cred, but not $cred which is a but strange, yet I am sure that at least their wiki is correct.

@alive-one Can you link to the guide/wiki article you're referring to?

@mathias-r-jessen Sure! Here is official wiki of SimplySQL Project, and their reference for MySQL connection https://github.com/mithrandyr/SimplySql/wiki/Open-MySqlConnection

Looking at the link, I think the docs should probably say -Credential $myuser with a $ on myuser. At the moment your code is giving a syntax error because it’s not valid Powershell code - when you fix that with -Credential $Cred it sounds like you’re then getting a runtime error instead - maybe network connectivity or incorrect login details. You need to fix the syntax error first (by adding a $ to Cred) and then investigate the runtime error…

I already tried that. I mean fixing syntax. Now and then it was connection error, yet I can connetc to MySQL server using same credentials via MySQl Workbencg, HeidiSQL and other software. So It seems the problem is not in wrong password and username, but with wrong processing of this values by SimplySQL or PSCredentials object, for that matters.
